# Slide to right using .animate () width

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

after reading all the questions related to this I still can't seem to figure out how to make it work for me.

I've got a list of social icons that I would like to have slide from left to right when hovering over "Follow Me" and then slide back into hiding when hovered away.

Here is the current code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattj06/NqrKK/3/)...

If you make the fix, can you point out where I made my mistakes? I'm still very new to this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but is pretty close to what you are asking for. I have stopped using UL and LI's for the icons and just used a div and spans, this can be changed back if required. The main issue is setting the width to a specific value (percent won't work).

```
$('.social-top').hide();

$('#social-grid').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.social-top').show();
    $('.social-top').stop().animate({
        width: 225
    }, 1000);
});

$('#social-grid').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.social-top').stop().animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('.social-top').hide();
    });

});​
```

This should get you most of the way there. I use show/hide to resolve an issue with 0 width and inline-block elements still being shown.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/NqrKK/13/

Comment: @MattJones I am glad I was able to help. Please feel free to accept this answer if you want (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

There are many logical flaws in your code:

1. Initially you are hiding the container, therefore closing all possibilities of the event ever being triggered
2. You selector itself is an li item and there is no child `<li>` inside it.
3. And Increasing the `width` property of the element does not take it to left. You need `left`, `right` or even `padding-left` or `margin-left`

Your syntactical mistake was, the properties to be animated and the time was inside the same curly braces. The correct syntax

```
$('element').animate(
   {
       //css properties
       left: "50"
   },
   5000 //The time in milliseconds or `fast`, `slow`
);
```

Use this

```
$('.social-top li:not(.social-flyout)').hover(function() {
    $('.social-top').animate({
        right: 0
    },"fast"
    );
});
```

I also gave `position: absolute` to the `.social-top`. Here is a working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/NqrKK/9/) here

Comment: Starx - my apologies. I accidentally shared the incorrect jsfiddle. This is the one I meant to share http://jsfiddle.net/mattj06/cVVuV/1/ Sorry!

Comment: Also just to reaffirm, I want the social icons to be hidden when the page loads. Then have them appear when hovering over "follow me"

Comment: @MattJones, Either way, the demo should be what you wanted. Isn't it? I am going out now, I will after 30mins

Comment: @MattJones, Here is a quick and update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/NqrKK/11/). You should get the point now